# Printing multiple values per line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

There is a variable to which text or numeric values are written. One word (or number) per line. How to print this data so that they are grouped by the desired number of values per line?
Example:

```
date = "
a,
b,
c,
111,
222,
444
"
```

Output for values_in_row = 4:

```
a, b, c, 111, 
222, 444
```

Output for values_in_row = 2:

```
a, b,
c, 111,
222, 444
```

Comment: Could you please clarify and format your expected input/output? It looks like you've listed the same thing over and over.

Comment: Can you give an example of how the output should look like? The current example seems to be the same for both the 4 values per row and the two values per row

Comment: what data structure is your va
riable "date"? is it a string? a list?

Comment: Your question is too broad. What did you try? Do you know how to make a list from your string `date`? Do you know how to loop over the elements of a list? Do you know the `%` (modulo) operator?

Comment: @samology string

Answer (score 0):

FYI, your question is formatted with Markdown, so make sure to view the preview before posting. It's been formatted in a way that hides what you're trying to do, but I see there are some edits queued so that should be fixed soon.

As for your actual question, you have data:

```
data = (
"a,"
"b,"
"c,"
"111,"
"222,"
"444"
)
```

This syntax will join all your lines together like:

```
data = "a,b,c,111,222,444"
```

Firstly split the data on the commas.

```
data = list(data.split(","))
```

Next, group your list into sub-lists of length `values_in_row`:

```
data = [data[i:i + values_in_row] for i in range(0, len(data), values_in_row)]
```

Which for `values_in_row = 4` would give you `[["a", "b", "c", "111"], ["222", "444"]]`

Now you could print each sublist like:

```
for sublist in data:
    print(sublist)
```

But in your question you joined them again with commas, including a trailing comma in all but the last line. Do that like this.

```
rows = [", ".join(sublist) for sublist in data]
number_of_rows = len(rows)
for i, row in enumerate(rows, start=1):
    if i == number_of_rows:    
        print(row)
    else:
        print(row + ",")
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: I made a typo and have fixed it now. It should have been `", ".join(sublist)`

Comment: It works, thanks. But at the end of the all line, ","

Comment: Do you want the comma?